# what is the shortcut to auto generate hashcode() and equals()?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a project (Java) and created an Object with a large number of variables. Since I am planning to add `hashcode()` and `equals()`. Is there a short cut in Eclipse to automatically generate `hashcode()` and `equals()` in a given class ?

Comment: http://azagorneanu.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-generate-equals-hashcode.html

Answer (score 4):

Ways to Generate hashcode() and equals() Method -

1) Press **Alt + Shift + S + H** 
2) **Right click** -> Source -> Generate hashcode() and equals() Method 
3) Go to **Source menu** -> Generate hashcode() and equals() Method 
4) Go to **Windows menu** -> Preferences  -> General -> Keys (Write Generate hashcode() and equals() Method on text field)

Answer (score 1):

- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>.

---

Another option is

- Go to **Window --> Preferences --> Click on General --> Keys**. You will see

[image]

Now, type *"hash"* and you can set command of your choice.

Some useful shortcuts are

1. [93 shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html)
2. [more shortcuts](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key)

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users: `Command` + `N` (`⌘N`)

IDE: Android Studio

[Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html#generate-equals-hashcode ]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a short cut in Eclipse to automatically generate hashcode() and equals() in a given class

Yes, Right click on the variable and source-> Generate hashcode() and equals().